# Does anyone know where I can find coremltools documentation?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, coreml

I need to convert a Keras model into the CoreML model format, but I can't find the CoreML documentation - all the links on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools aren't working, and pythonhosted.org isn't working, either.

Comment: I've been hosting a copy of the code: https://github.com/gsabran/coremltools and I think here are some parameter of interest: https://github.com/gsabran/coremltools/blob/master/_scripts/converter.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a web cache search engines like http://cachedview.com/ to get the last working version of a website.

Here's the google archived link to the pythonhosted site: 
 http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://pythonhosted.org/coremltools/

And heres the pypi cached site:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools